# How to make the same scope available in two div's with different data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

```
$rootScope.getPricesData = function (typ) {
        var data = {
            type: typ
        }
        $http({
            url: '...',
            method: 'POST',
            data: data
        }).then(function (res) {
            $rootScope.pricesData = res.data;
            console.log(res);
        })
    }
```

And its works good and html

```
<div ng-init="getPricesData('template')">info template</div>
<div ng-init="getPricesData('subscription_month')">info subscription_month</div>
```

and I see in these two div's information about subscription(not tempate and subscription) in Console i see this data correctly, and the function was called twice (for template and subscription).

I think the scope overrides (but I do not know how to fix that)
Please for help

Comment: if you declared the controller in router and also in controller it will be called twice ... remove any one of them

Comment: Never ever try using the rootscope thats a bad practice

Comment: Instead you can make use of a directive

Comment: overall design of whatever you are trying to make is very bad.
however you can make `$rootScope.pricesData` and array and push data in it whenever received, or like suggested by Christian Esperar (make an object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use Javascript [**ternary operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to handle the scenario **.**

  ```
  $rootScope.getPricesData = function (typ) {
      var data = {
          type: typ
      }
      $http({
          url: '...',
          method: 'POST',
          data: data
      }).then(function (res) {
          if(typ == 'template') ? $scope.templatePricesData = res.data : $scope.subscriptionPricesData = res.data;
      })
  }
  ```
- You can create one empty object and then on success response assign the response data into the respective properties of an object.

  ```
  $scope.resData = {};
  $rootScope.getPricesData = function (typ) {
      var data = {
          type: typ
      }
      $http({
          url: '...',
          method: 'POST',
          data: data
      }).then(function (res) {
          $scope.resData[typ] = res.data;
      })
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will always override. One possible solution is make your $rootScope an **object** so it can be like **$rootScope.pricesData[typ]**